# How to get model data after save ( CakePHP )

Tags: cakephp

I want to get the latest data from the model after it has saved without doing another select.

Currently I do this:

```
if ($this->Model->save($data)){
    $last = $this->Model->find('first',array(
        'conditions' => array('Model.id' => $this->Model->id)
    );
    $last['Model']['dataChangedByBehaviors']; // <-- data I want
}
```

I want to get any data that was set in model callbacks or behaviors without performing an extra find.

Comment: Can you clarify, I don't really understand what you're asking.

Comment: i want get data like $last in above example that don't need to select database.

Comment: Please review again this questions and answers. I have the feeling it is still not clear. And also as it's some time ago, did you solve it in the meantime your own or what was your solution / alternative?

Answer (score 15):

I'm not understand why people doing labor work. Just use getLastInsertId() CakePHP's inbuilt function and it's done :

```
$post_id=$this->Post->getLastInsertId();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 12):

There are two different situations for your example:

- *$data* holds a complete record of your model data. Then you can simply access *$data['Model']['dataChangeByBehaviors']*:

```
if ($this->Model->save($data)){
      $data['Model']['dataChangeByBehaviors'];  //---- I want get this
}
```

So, here the answer is: You already have the data.

(Note: If it's a new record, *$data* will of course not contain the ID, which you need to get from *$this->Model->id*. And if you are making any changes in the *beforeSave()* callback, these will of course not be reflected in your *$data*).

- *$data* only contains certain fields that you update in a record. Then there is no other way to get the complete record, apart from reading it from the database - which is what you are doing already and can be simplified as suggested by Leo:

```
if ($this->Model->save($data)){
      $last = $this->Model->read(null,$this->Model->id);
      $last['Model']['dataChangeByBehaviors'];  //---- I want get this
}
```

So here the answer is: There is no way of getting the data without a database request.

Comment: Most explanatory answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for some solution like *if ($last = $this->Model->save($data))*, I think there's no such thing as that.

But you can save some code using findById:

```
if ($this->Model->save($data)){
      $last = $this->Model->findById($this->Model->id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't but a simple read is fastest

```
  $last = $this->Model->read(null,$this->Model->id);
```